# Add a date column to csv using python

Tags: python, csv

I have the following code which writes a data output to a csv file. I want to add a date variable at the end of each row using the yesterday.strftime variable that i am using in creating the filename. For example:

Thanks!

my current output is like:

columnA

1

2

and I want to add the following column:

Date

2/5/2016

2/5/2016

.
.
.

CODE::

```
filepath = 'C:\\test\\'   
filename = yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '_' + 'test.csv'

f = open( filename, 'wt')
writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
header = [h['name'][3:] for h in results.get('columnHeaders')] 
writer.writerow(header)
print(''.join('%30s' % h for h in header))

# Write data table.
if results.get('rows', []):
  for row in results.get('rows'):
    writer.writerow(row)
    print(''.join('%30s' % r for r in row))

else:
  print ('No Rows Found')

f.close()
```

Comment: Where does `results` come from? You might have to look there

Comment: FYI, you can replace `if results.get('rows', []):`, `for row in results.get('rows'):` with just `if results.get('rows'):`, `for row in results['rows']:`; the first usage doesn't use the default for anything but a boolean test (so the default default of `None` is fine), and the second already knows the key exists, so no need to use `.get` at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [26]: import pandas as pd

In [27]: import datetime

In [28]: a = pd.read_csv('a.csv')

In [29]: a
Out[29]: 
columnA
0        1
1        2

In [30]: a['Date'] = [datetime.date.today()]*len(a)

In [31]: a
Out[31]: 
columnA        Date
0        1  2016-02-05
1        2  2016-02-05

In [32]: a.to_csv('adate.csv')
```

Generally: https://www.airpair.com/python/posts/top-mistakes-python-big-data-analytics

Comment: First off thanks for posting. I ran the code, but it's adding an index field of some sort to the beginning of my file. Is there a way for me to omit that or give it a name? currently it's just blank.